# How can I loop over multiple values in OPA to validate

Tags: regex, open-policy-agent, rego

I have '**JSON**' file something like below, now i want to validate is label cat is set or not?

```
"labels": {
"apple": "one",
"banana": "two",
"cat": "three"
    }
      
check_against_targets(value, targets) {
    mode == "allowlist"
    match_mode == "regex"
    not my_regexp.match_name(value, targets)
}
check_labels(labels) {
    print(count(labels))
    count(labels) > 0
    some i
    check_against_targets(labels[i])
}
```

with above OPA test its only taking first label and not going through all labels to validate it.

any idea where i'm going wrong (I am quite new to OPA).

expected behaviour is should go through all labels and find CAT is their or not!

Answer (score 0):

The example isn't complete, but I'll do my best to answer :) As soon as a function body evaluates, it'll return `true` unless a different return value has been defined. In your case you're using negation (i.e. `not my_regexp.match_name(value, targets)`) which naturally will be true as the first label *does not* match...

Adding to that, you're only passing one argument to `check_against_targets` which should take two, so I'm not sure what the expected outcome here would be? If you're only looking to answer whether the `cat` key is in the object or not, you could just do something like:

```
package p

import future.keywords.in

labels := {
    "apple": "one",
    "banana": "two",
    "cat": "three",
}

has_cat_key {
    "cat" in object.keys(labels)
}
```

If you have some custom function for validating keys, you'd use that without the negation:

```
package p

import future.keywords.in

labels := {
    "apple": "one",
    "banana": "two",
    "cat": "three",
}

# Check if *any* key matches
has_key_match {
    some key in object.keys(labels)
    my_matcher(key)
}

my_key_matcher(key) {
    # ... matching implementation here
}
```

If you want to validate that **all** keys match some criteria, you could use the [every](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#every-keyword) keyword.